# Pandas apply() with multiple arguments in multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing, apply

I have a big data set made of a million records (which is represented in the following snippet as big_df with just 5 rows) and I would like to use multiprocessing when invoking apply function which is calling `classify function`.

Problem statement
Data set is composed of 1M which every row includes the columns `id` and `name`, the latest column `name` includes punctuations and stopwords which are removed using regex. Then, we can assume the names shown in dataframe are already cleaned.

For each record is needed to go word by word to identify if that word is used at the beginning or/and at the end, it can be both. For instance, if we have the word `ABC SECONDARY SCHOOL BOARDING`:

- `ABC` is just at the beginning in the same name `ABC SCHOOL BOARDING`,
  it does not have `classification end`. Then, it is counted as 1 at the `classification start`.
- `SECONDARY` is the second word and it is not
  found neither at the start or end. Then, it is classified
  as `none`.
- `SCHOOL` is the third word and it is found just at the end in `MARIE INSTITUTE SCHOOL`,`RALPH ELEMENTARY SCHOOL` and `BOARDING SCHOOL`.
  Then, it is counted as 3 at the `classification end`.
- `BOARDING` is the forth word and it is found at the end in `ABC SCHOOL BOARDING` and counted as 1 at the `classification end`. In addition, `BOARDING` is found at the beginning in `BOARDING SCHOOL`, then it is counted as
  1 at `classification start`.

This process continues until reaching all the rows. Then, an aggregation is performed to get how many times a word was at the beginning and/or end, if none, the word is classified as `none`.

The following is a working version simply invoking the function `classify` using apply:

```
import pandas as pd
Data=[[0,'ABC SECONDARY SCHOOL BOARDING',['ABC','SECONDARY','SCHOOL','BOARDING']],
      [1,'UNIVERSITY BOARDING INSTITUTE',['UNIVERSITY','BOARDING','INSTITUTE']],
      [2,'MARIE INSTITUTE SCHOOL',['MARIE', 'INSTITUTE','SCHOOL']],
      [3,'RALPH ELEMENTARY SCHOOL',['RALPH','ELEMENTARY','SCHOOL']],
      [4,'BOARDING SCHOOL',['BOARDING','SCHOOL']]]

df_big=pd.DataFrame(Data, columns=['id','name', 'name_list'])
df_class = pd.DataFrame(columns=['word','classification'])
df_class2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['word','classification'])

def classify(row,start,end):
    d=[]
    for word in row.name_list:
        flag=False
        if word in start.values:
            d.append([word,'start'])
            flag=True
        if word in end.values:
            d.append([word,'end'])
            flag=True
        if (not flag):
            d.append([word,'none'])
    return d  

df_start=pd.DataFrame(columns=['name'])
df_end=pd.DataFrame(columns=['name'])
df_start= df_big.name.str.split().str.get(0).drop_duplicates(keep="last")
df_end= df_big.name.str.split().str.get(-1).drop_duplicates(keep="last")

lst=[]

lst = df.apply(classify, args=[df_start, df_end],axis=1)

flat_list = [item for sublist in lst for item in sublist]
lst=[]

for e in flat_list:
    lst.append(e)

print("--------")
print("Dataframe classified:")
df2=pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['word', 'classification'])
print(df2)

print("Summary")
df2.index.names = ['id']
df2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
count_series=df2.groupby(['word','classification']).size()
df_count = count_series.to_frame(name = 'counter').reset_index()

print(df_count)
```

This provides a result as follows:

```
Dataframe classified:
          word classification
0          ABC          start
1    SECONDARY           none <------SPECIAL CASE, NOT CLASSIFIED
2       SCHOOL            end
3     BOARDING          start
4     BOARDING            end
5   UNIVERSITY          start
6     BOARDING          start
7     BOARDING            end
8    INSTITUTE            end
9        MARIE          start
10   INSTITUTE            end
11      SCHOOL            end
12       RALPH          start
13  ELEMENTARY           none <------SPECIAL CASE, NOT CLASSIFIED
14      SCHOOL            end
15    BOARDING          start
16    BOARDING            end
17      SCHOOL            end

Summary
         word classification  counter
0         ABC          start        1
1    BOARDING            end        3
2    BOARDING          start        3
3  ELEMENTARY           none        1  <---NONE
4   INSTITUTE            end        2
5       MARIE          start        1
6       RALPH          start        1
7      SCHOOL            end        4
8   SECONDARY           none        1  <---NONE
9  UNIVERSITY          start        1
```

Basically, every single word is classified as `start`,`end` or `none` with respect to the whole dataset.

The above version is working and producing the results shown. However, with a dataset made of million records this is delaying about 10 hours. I need to do the same in a faster way. In my search, I come up with `multiprocessing` to help speeding up the process through splitting the big dataset based on the number of cores and run each part of dataset in parallel.

Then, I added the following modification:

```
def process(df,df_start,df_end):
    return df.apply(classify, args=[df_start, df_end],axis=1)   

p = mp.Pool(processes=8)
split_dfs = np.array_split(big_df,8)
pool_results = p.map(process, split_dfs)
p.close()
p.join()

# merging parts processed by different processes
parts = pd.concat(pool_results, axis=0)

# merging newly calculated parts to big_df
big_df = pd.concat([big_df, parts], axis=1)

# checking if the dfs were merged correctly
pdt.assert_series_equal(parts['id'], big_df['id'])
```

However, this modification is still running with no results. I was wondering how to get working apply() with several parameters in a faster way.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Apply with a lamda function would probably work well

Comment: I don't think this can run, even without multiprocessing involved?

Comment: Why do you want to use multiprocessing? Have you done all the due diligence involved with parallelism/concurrency? Can you explain what your program is actually meant to do?

Comment: I added the logic and results in the simplest form. The idea is to apply a function to each row to find for each word in the name what is its position with respect to the whole dataset (which originally is 1 M). Then, a word can be at the end or start depending on the evaluation done in the function `classify`. I would like to split the big dataframe and run simultaneously, then join the results and sort by word and classification as it is done in the simplest form.

Comment: `pandas` seems like entirely the wrong tool for all of this. Simply looping over a list and using a `dict` to keep counts of the start and end would be very fast, even for millions of items.

Comment: Can you explain more @juanpa.arrivallaga?

Comment: What you are doing is not an effective use of pandas. Just using vanilla Python to get counts of start-and -end would be very fast, even for millions of rows. Certainly nowhere near 10 hours

Comment: Either something is not correct in your code, or I don't understand your output. Are you trying to get the counts of start and end words? Or are you trying to get the count of words anywhere, so long as they are a start and end word at least once?

Comment: The final results is an aggregation of the section `Dataframe classified` which I included in the post

Comment: Can you please just describe what you are trying to accomplish? I am certain it can be done very quickly without pandas at all.

Comment: Your output doesn't match the description. Are you basically trying to get a count of the words at the beginning, and words that occur at the end, and ignore the words that occur in the middle? What if there is only one word, or no words?

Comment: Why is boarding being counted as being `end` 3 times? `BOARDING            end        3`?

Comment: If a word is not at the `start` or `end`, then this word is classified as `none`. As in the example, the words `SECONDARY` or  `ELEMENTARY` are unclassified and marked as `none`, they are in the middle always.

Comment: Why is boarding counted as end 3 times?

Comment: Word `BOARDING` is counted as 3 because it appears in id 0,1,4 and the word `BOARDING` is at the beginning and the end.

Comment: Word `BOARDING` is counted as 3 because it appears in id 0,1,4 and the word `BOARDING` is at the beginning and the end. The id 0 finds `BOARDING` at the end itself and at start in id 4, then `start`=1, `end`=1. The id 1 has `BOARDING` in the middle, but it finds `BOARDING` at the end in id 0 and at the beginning in id 4, then, `start`=2, `end`=2. Then, id 4 has `BOARDING` at the end , then counts itself and  id 4 which is at the beginning, then `start`=3 and `end`=3

Answer (score 0):

Python (and inherently Pandas) often struggles with processing larger data sets (especially if functions are not vectorized - see a decent article on how to improve that [here](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) ) without some special setup.

Keeping that on the back burner and trying to solve the problem at hand (finding matching words in a list of values):

You could create one dataframe for `end` words and one data frame for `start` words (assuming a word can be both `start` and `end`).

Then you would want to do two left merges. These should be pretty fast.

```
out_start=pd_big.merge(pd_start,left_on='word',right_on='word',how='left')
out_both=out_start.merge(pd_end,left_on='word',right_on='word',how='left')
```

You will probably want to do some re naming, but this should be much faster.

You can find more on pandas merging here: (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)